# unitary operators, ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this exercise:
Given the following ODE
$$\dot{\bf{x}} = A\bf{x}, \bf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2, A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & a 
\end{bmatrix} $$
I need to find the values of $a,b,c$ s.t. $$|\bf{x}(t)|^2 = |\bf{x}(0)|^2$$
My approach was the following:
We know that $|\bf{v}|^2 = \langle\bf{v}, \bf{v} \rangle$, moreover we know that $$x(t) = U(t)x(0), U(t) = e^{tA}$$
Therefore we get:
$$ \langle U \bf{x}(0),U\bf{x}(0)\rangle = \langle \bf{x}(0),\bf{x}(0)\rangle $$
This means that $U$ must be a unitary operator, which preserves the inner product.
Now from a proposition written by my professor in one of his lectures, which I have to yet demonstrate (tried but failed), I know that 
*$e^{i \alpha A}, \alpha = const$ is unitary if $A$ is a self-adjoint matrix*
therefore I tried this:
$$ e^{tA} = e^{it(-iA)} = e^{itB}, B= -iA$$
Now I just need to find the values of $a,b,c$ which make $-iA$ self-adjoint, thus:
\begin{align*}
-ia = i\bar{a}\\
-ib = i\bar{c}\\
i\bar{b} = -ic
\end{align*}
From the first equation I get $$a = x+iy \Rightarrow x+iy= -(x-iy) \Rightarrow x = -x \Rightarrow a = 0$$
subtracting the third eq from the second one I get:
$$ b = \alpha + i\beta, c = l + im \Rightarrow b + \bar{b} + c + \bar{c} \Rightarrow 2\alpha + 2l  = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = -l \Rightarrow \Re\{b\} = -\Re\{c\}$$
If I solve the second and the third one separately instead, I end up with the condition $\Im(b) = \Im(c)$
Now I'm having some trouble, mainly because I don't understand why I'm getting different results. Secondly, the solution tells me that the conditions are:
$$ a = 0, bc < 0$$
My professor's solution tells me that those conditions can be found by noticing that for $e^{tA}$ to be unitary, the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 $of $A$ must be purely imaginary numbers. Nevertheless, I couldn't find a demonstration of this particular fact anywhere. Can someone tell me how to prove this? Moreover, why does it seem that we don't arrive at the same conclusions by sticking to my original solution?

Comment: If $A$ is self adjoint then since $(i A)^* = - i A$ we see that $(e^{iA})^* e^{iA} = e^0 = I$. Any real symmetric matric is self adjoint.

Comment: Is $$(e^{iA})^* = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left(\overline{(iA)}^T\right)^n = e^{(iA)^*}$$ correct?I was trying to prove your second equality

Comment: Well, for any square $B$ we have $(e^B)^* = e^{B^*}$ directly from the definition.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three equations are simply, after dividing by $i$ and after noting that the second and third equations are the same (they are conjugates of each other),
$$
-a=\overline a,\qquad\qquad -b=\overline c.
$$
But $a,b,c$ are assumed real and so the equations are in fact
$$
-a=a,\qquad\qquad -b=c. 
$$
So
$$\tag1
a=0,\qquad\qquad c=-b.
$$
The solution you mention is wrong. For instance the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&2\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} 
$$
satisfies $a=0$, $bc<0$, but
$$
e^{tA}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\sqrt2&\sqrt2\,\sin\sqrt2\\-\frac{\sqrt2}2\,\sin\sqrt2&\cos\sqrt2\end{bmatrix} 
$$
is not a unitary. For instance, with $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ you get
\begin{align}
\left\langle e^{tA}x,e^{tA}x\right\rangle
&=\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} \cos\sqrt2\\ -\frac{\sqrt2}2\,\sin\sqrt2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} \cos\sqrt2\\ -\frac{\sqrt2}2\,\sin\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle\\[0.2cm]
&=\cos^2\sqrt2+\frac12\,\sin\sqrt2\\[0.2cm]
&\ne1=\langle x,x\rangle. 
\end{align}

As for the eigenvalues, if $U$ is a unitary and $Ux=\lambda x$ with $x$ a unit vector,  then $$|\lambda|^2=\langle \lambda x,\lambda x\rangle=\langle Ux,Ux\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle=1.$$ That is $|\lambda|=1$. On the other hand, one can see using for instance the Jordan form that the eigenvalues of $e^{tA}$ are precisely $\{e^{t\lambda}:\ \lambda\ \text{ is an eigenvalue of }A\}$. So for $e^{tA}$ to be a unitary you need that the eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $|e^{t\lambda}|=1$. That is
$$
1=|e^{t\operatorname{Re}\lambda}\,e^{i\operatorname{Im}\lambda}|=e^{t\operatorname{Re}\lambda},
$$
which forces $\operatorname{Re}\lambda=0$. That is, $\lambda$ has to be imaginary. If $A$ is of the form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0& b\\-b&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
then its eigenvalues are the roots of $\lambda^2+b^2=0$, that is $\pm ib$; so they are imaginary. Conversely, if $A$ has imaginary eigenvalues and
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} a& b\\c&a\end{bmatrix},
$$
the eigenvalues of $A$ are
$$
a\pm\sqrt{bc}.
$$
But imaginary eigenvalues of $A$ are a necessary condition for $e^{tA}$ to be a unitary; not a sufficient one. What we may note is that if $A=\begin{bmatrix} a& b\\c&a\end{bmatrix}$ then we may write it as
$$
A=aI+K, 
$$
where $K=\begin{bmatrix} 0& b\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$. As $K$ and $I$ commute, we have
$$
e^{tA}=e^{taI+tK}=e^{taI}\,e^{tK}=e^{ta}\,e^{tK}.
$$
If $e^{tA}$ is a unitary we have
$$\tag2
I=e^{tA}\,(e^{tA})^*=e^{ta}\,e^{tK}\,e^{ta}\,e^{tK^*}=e^{2ta}\,e^{t(K+K^*)}.
$$
In particular $e^{t(K+K^*)}$ is a scalar matrix. It is easy to calculate that
$$
e^{t(K+K^*)}=\begin{bmatrix} \cosh t(b+c)& \sinh t(b+c)\\ \sinh t(b+c)&\cosh t(b+c)\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Thus $\sinh t(b+c)=0$, which gives $t(b+c)=0$ and hence $c=-b$. In particular $K+K^*=0$, so $(2)$ becomes $1=e^{2ta}$, which forces $a=0$. Hence
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&b\\-b&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$

Comment: This is such a thorough answer. I couldn't be more grateful right now. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help!